# Why doesn't this work displaying 2 images

Tags: php, mysqli

It only displays one image I want to display 2 images
I want to display several images but with other table information, but first I want to know how to display more than one image

```
 <?php
 $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT link FROM images WHERE ID = 1");
$stmt->bind_param("i", $ID);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($link);
$stmt->fetch();

?>
<img id="result_img" src="<?php echo $link; ?>" /> 


<?php
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT link FROM images WHERE ID = 2");
$stmt->bind_param("i", $ID);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($link);
$stmt->fetch();

?>
 <img id="result_img" src="<?php echo $link; ?>" />
```

Comment: You should paste the output that you are getting from two echo functions.

Comment: Questions asking "Why doesn't this work" considered offtopic here.

Comment: $stmt1 = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT link FROM images WHERE ID = 2"); change varibles of second image..i think conflict beetween first image varible with second image

Comment: Not sure if it's causing a problem, but I notice you're using `bind_param`, but there aren't any placeholders in the query (you've hard-coded `ID = 1`, rather than `ID = ?`).

Answer (score -1):

Try like this,

```
 $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT link FROM images WHERE ID = ?");
 $stmt->bind_param("i", $ID);
 $stmt->execute();
 $stmt->bind_result($link);
 $stmt->fetch();
 $stmt->store_result();

 if( $stmt->num_rows > 0 )
 {
    while( $stmt->fetch() ) 
    {
       echo '<img id="result_img" src="'.$link.'" />';
    }
 }

 /* for second link just use already prepared query */
 $stmt->bind_param("i", $ID2);
 $stmt->execute();
 $stmt->bind_result($link);
 $stmt->fetch();
 $stmt->store_result();

 if( $stmt->num_rows > 0 )
 {
    while( $stmt->fetch() ) 
    {
       echo '<img id="result_img" src="'.$link.'" />';
    }
 }
```